# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable . how to solve this problem

Tags: python, module, typeerror

```
y_train = y_train.reshape(-1,)

    y_train[:5]
    
    y_test = y_test.reshape(-1,)
    
    nwclasses= classes
    nwclasses = ["airplane","automobile","bird","cat","deer","dog","frog","horse","ship","truck"]
    def plot_sample(X, y, index):
        plt.figure(figsize = (15,2))
        plt.imshow(X[index])
        plt.xlabel(classes[y[index]]) 
    plot_sample(X_train, y_train, 1)
```

**TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 plot_sample(X_train, y_train, 1)

```
<ipython-input-34-4fb71385cd26> in plot_sample(X, y, index)
      1 def plot_sample(X, y, index):
----> 2     plt.figure(figsize = (15,2))
      3     plt.imshow(X[index])
      4     plt.xlabel(classes[y[index]])

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable**
```

Comment: How have you imported `matplotlib`, can you please show?

Comment: Show us where `plt` is assigned. Is it an import?

Comment: yes I import matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

`figure` is a module in matplotlib, us the `figure.Figure` class instead:

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize = (15,2))
```

Comment: AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'imshow' . I got this error now? what to do?

Comment: @noobcode use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`